# gsub First-name Last-name to FL

Tags: r, gsub

I would like to change a range of names to simply their initials,

Say I have two names `c("Ben Franklin", "Millard Fillmore")` and I would like to subset them to `c("BF", "MF")`, I have read the help fil eto `?gsub` but I cannot figure it out. Can anyone here help me?

Comment: @agstudy, I fooled around with `gsub`, but I do not understand it to a lavel where I could come up with what you and others have suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This removes everything that is not an upper case letter:

```
> s <- c("Ben Franklin", "Millard Fillmore")
> gsub("[^A-Z]", "", s)
[1] "BF" "MF"
```

Here is a more complex regular expression if you have strings such "Allan McCormick" as per comments:

```
s <- c("Ben Franklin", "Millard Fillmore", "Allen McCormick")
gsub("(.)\\S* *", "\\1", s)
[1] "BF" "MF" "AM"
```

Comment: quite elegant!! ... if we can assume first letters of names are always capitalized (seems reasonable)... although it fails with something like "McCormick"

Comment: I compared the answers on speed and this is by far the fastest, on my real data. Furthermore, this example account for names that are more then two words long, and even have a extra example for names like McCormick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Split the strings on `" "`, then apply the `substr` function to each component and collapse the results with paste

```
> x <- c("Ben Franklin", "Millard Fillmore")
> sapply(strsplit(x, " "), function(x) paste(substr(x, 1, 1), collapse=""))
[1] "BF" "MF"
```

Answer (score 1):

just with gsub

```
 gsub(pattern='(.)(.*)[[:space:]](.)(.*)','\\1\\3',c("Ben Franklin", "Millard Fillmore"))

 "BF" "MF"
```

Comment: You could make this a little shorter: `gsub("^(.).* (.).*", "\\1\\2", x)`  But, it still makes the assumption that there are only 2 names per person.  If someone has a middle name, the middle initial will not be used (which may be desirable).

Comment: @GSee You re right! maybe you have a long name to have such reflex :)